# Modifying a tensor according to a boolean tensor in torch

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I want to do some operations on a tensor according to a boolean tensor. For example, let's assume we have this tensor : `L=torch.tensor([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]])` and a boolean tensor `Lbool=torch.tensor([[[True,False,False],[False,True,False]],[[False,False,True],[True,False,False]]])`.

I would like to do the following operation without doing a loop in order to enjoy of cuda advantages : If there is a True at the index (i,j) in Lbool, i want to do +1 at the index (i+1,j) in L. We ignore the possible boundaries issues here. `L=torch.tensor([[[1,3,3],[4,5,7]],[[7,8,9],[10,12,12]]])`

Is there a way to do this properly in torch ?